# QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype *** for property ***

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to use a nested QObject structure in QML, because the nested object should receive necessary parameters from the first-level object. The structure looks as follows.

The solution builds, but when I try to run it, I received the error:

```
QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'Projector' for property 'Backend::projector'
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "backend.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

  qmlRegisterType<Backend>("com.company.backend", 1, 0, "Backend");

  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

  return app.exec();
}
```

*main.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import com.company.backend 1.0


Window
{

....

ComboBox {
        id: projector
        currentIndex: 2
        model: backend.projector.list
        width: 180
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: projectorListLabel.bottom
        anchors.leftMargin: 15
        anchors.topMargin: 5
    }

...

}
```

*backend.h*

```
...

#include "projector.h"

class Backend : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(Projector projector READ getProjector NOTIFY projectorChanged)

public:
  Projector* getProjector() const;

signals:
  void projectorChanged();
```

*backend.cpp*

```
...

#include "backend.h"

Backend::Backend(QObject* parent) {

  _projector = new Projector();
  emit(projectorChanged());
}

Projector* Backend::getProjector() const {
  return _projector;
}
```

*projector.h*

```
...

class Projector : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

  Q_PROPERTY(QStringList list READ getList WRITE setList NOTIFY listChanged)

 public:
  explicit Projector(QObject* parent = nullptr);

 QStringList getList() const;

 public slots:
  void setList(QStringList list);

 signals:
  void listChanged();

 private:
  QStringList _list;
};
```

*projector.cpp*

```
...

#include "projector.h"

#include <iostream>

Projector::Projector(QObject* parent) {}

QStringList Projector::getList() const {
  return _list;
}

void Projector::setList(QStringList list) {
  std::cout << "Updating list" << std::endl;
  _list = list;
  listChanged();
}
```

I have read some article about registering the meta-type and using macros, but I have not found any source that explains this thoroughly.

Comment: You also need to register Projector with qmlRegisterType.

Answer (score 0):

QT needs to know the definitions of the types you'll be using for signals/slots etc.

The type can be declared at compilation time using the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro

However, you also probably need to register it at runtime to enable the creation of new instances. This is done through the qRegisterMetatype() method.

See [this link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/custom-types.html) for the full documentation which explains this nicely